# Courier Fee for UK visa when all family members apply separately

Tags: visas, uk, fees-and-charges

We are a family of six and are applying for a visa to visit the UK. We were told to do separate application per family member, linked by inputing the primary GWF number in other applications.

As we all live together, do we have to pay for the courier that will return our documents to our address for each applicant separately or we can simply pay cost of a single courier to reduce cost?

Comment: Please do not use your cap lock key.

Answer (score 4):

You have to pay the courier fee for each applicant separately, even if the packages arrive together they need to be paid for individually. You can't send multiple applications for the cost of one.

Every cost related to an application will need to be paid for each applicant, regardless of whether they apply together and are a family.

> (Application Fee + VFS Fee + Courier Fee + Value Added Services) **x Number of Applicants**